# Using my mobile to launch apps on my desktop computer

Tags: android, automation

I want to launch applications on my desktop computer via my mobile. The only thing that comes a bit close to a solution is the software "TweetMyPC", but the problem is, I don't want to use Twitter for this. A full remote desktop implementation is overkill as I want to launch an application as fast as possible, and I don't want to mess with setting up my own VPN solution for access (So I'll probably need some third party provider for this).

Simple use case scenario:

Enter "start backup" on my mobile -> message is routed to my desktop pc -> Listener application receives the command and launches a predefined backup-script.

I thought this would be easy, but my google-skills didn't find any software solution which does this.

FYI: my desktop pc is a Windows 7, my mobile is Android 4.0

Comment: There is [sRemote](http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/sremote-run-remote-commands-to-your-pc-via-gmail/) it lets you use gmail to send command to your computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Software Recommendations https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer makes a great app and would take care of this for you.  It is however a full remote control system.  It can take care of your VPN, remote control, and file transfer.  Plus its free.  I use it to control all my PC's remotely.

Comment: Looks good indeed. In fact, almost perfect :-) The mouse navigation is a bit of a pain (I want to tap the icons on my desktop directly instead of moving the mouse cursor to it first).

Comment: It's the best free solution I have found.  Runs on port 80 as well so firewalls mean nothing to it.

Comment: Did this work, are you using it as your solution?